# Threads: Fine with 10, Crash with 10000

Tags: c++

Can someone please explain why the following code crashes:

```
int a(int x)
{
    int s = 0;
    for(int i = 0; i < 100; i++)
        s += i;
    return s;
}

int main()
{
    unsigned int thread_no = 10000;
    vector<thread> t(thread_no);

    for(int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
        t[i] = std::thread(a, 10);

    for(thread& t_now : t)
        t_now.join();

    cout << "OK" << endl;
    cin.get();
}
```

**But WORKS with 10 threads?** I am new to multithreading and simply don't understand what is happening?!

Comment: How does it crash? What's the error message?

Comment: `Fatal program exit requested.`

Comment: `__fastfail(FAST_FAIL_FATAL_APP_EXIT);`

Comment: I tried this on a windows 8.1 PC and one windows 7 PC and crashes on both.

Comment: may be the thread_no 10000 is  thread number limit in your system

Comment: what is `the thread limit`?

Comment: Gee, what are you going to do, not being able to take advantage of all 12,000 of your cores ...

Comment: Each thread takes a megabyte of memory. 10000 threads is ten gigabytes. That's a lot. std::thread probably threw a low memory exception. Unhandled exceptions result in application termination.

Comment: Heh, this crashes also with a mere 30 threads

Comment: Yeah, `10000` sounds a bit excessive.

Comment: Is your programmed compiled as 32-bit or 64-bit?  If it's 32-bit, then you may be running out of virtual address space.  Each thread is typically allocated several MB of stack space, and even though that memory isn't committed right away, it's still very easy to run out of your 4 GB of virtual address space with thousands of threads.

Comment: OMG. Just use debugger!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This creates a vector of 10,000 default-initialized threads:

```
unsigned int thread_no = 10000;
vector<thread> t(thread_no);
```

You're running into the difference between "capacity" and "size". You didn't just create a vector large enough to house 10,000 threads, you created a vector *of 10,000 threads*.

See the following (http://ideone.com/i7LBQ6)

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

struct Foo {
    Foo() { std::cout << "Foo()\n"; }
};

int main() {
    std::vector<Foo> f(8);
    std::cout << "f.capacity() = " << f.capacity() << ", size() = " << f.size() << '\n';
}
```

You only initialize 10 of the elements as running threads

```
for(int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
    t[i] = std::thread(a, 10);
```

So your for loop is going to see 10 initialized threads and then 9,990 un-started threads.

```
for(thread& t_now : t)
    t_now.join();
```

You might want to try using `t.reserve(thread_no);` and `t.emplace_back(a, 10);`

Here's a complete example with renaming.

```
int threadFn(int iterations)
{
    int s = 0;
    for(int i = 0; i < iterations; i++)
        s += i;
    return s;
}

int main()
{
    enum {
        MaximumThreadCapacity = 10000,
        DesiredInitialThreads = 10,
        ThreadLoopIterations = 100,
    };

    vector<thread> threads;
    threads.reserve(MaximumThreadCapacity);

    for(int i = 0; i < DesiredInitialThreads; i++)
        threads.emplace_back(threadFn, ThreadLoopIterations);

    std::cout << threads.size() << " threads spun up\n";

    for(auto& t : threads) {
        t.join();
    }

    std::cout << "threads joined\n";
}
```

---- EDIT ----

Specifically, the crash you are getting is the attempt to join a non-running thread, http://ideone.com/OuLMyQ

```
#include <thread>

int main() {
    std::thread t;
    t.join();
    return 0;
}
```

stderr

```
terminate called after throwing an instance of 'std::system_error'
  what():  Invalid argument
```

I point this out because you should be aware there is a race condition even with a valid thread, if you do

```
if (t.joinable())
    t.join();
```

it's possible for 't' to become non-joinable between the test and the action. You should always put a t.join() in a try {} clause. See http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/thread/join

Complete example:

```
int threadFn(int iterations)
{
    int s = 0;
    for(int i = 0; i < iterations; i++)
        s += i;
    return s;
}

int main()
{
    enum {
        MaximumThreadCapacity = 10000,
        DesiredInitialThreads = 10,
        ThreadLoopIterations = 100,
    };

    vector<thread> threads;
    threads.reserve(MaximumThreadCapacity);

    for(int i = 0; i < DesiredInitialThreads; i++)
        threads.emplace_back(threadFn, ThreadLoopIterations);

    std::cout << threads.size() << " threads spun up\n";

    for(auto& t : threads) {
        try {
            if(t.joinable())
                t.join();
        } catch (std::system_error& e) {
            switch (e.code()) {
            case std::errc::invalid_argument:
            case std::errc::no_such_process:
                continue;

            case std::errc::resource_deadlock_would_occur:
                std::cerr << "deadlock during join - wth!\n";
                return e.code();

            default:
                std::cout << "error during join: " << e.what() << '\n';
                return e.code();
            }
        }
    }

    std::cout << "threads joined\n";
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You create a vector that has 10000 elements in it, you then populate the first ten and you wait for all the the threads inside the vector to join. Your program crashes because you forgot to set the other 9990.

```
for(int i = 0; i < 10; i++) // Wrong
for(int i = 0; i < thread_no; i++) // Correct
```